# MySql Single Table, Select last 1 days and include empty rows

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have searched similar problems here on stackoverflow but I could not understand how to make this work, what I'm trying to do...

So, I want to get last 1 day meetings from database and get total meeting count and also include empty rows if there is no data for that day

Assume current date is 6/6/2020

```
Meeting_Table

+-------------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Meeting_ID        | User_ID       | Date_Start         |
+-------------------+---------------+--------------------+
| 101010            |             1 |6/5/2020 5:30:00 AM |
| 101011            |             2 |6/5/2020 4:30:00 AM |
| 101012            |             3 |6/4/2020 3:30:00 AM |
| 101013            |             4 |6/3/2020 8:30:00 AM |
| 101014            |             5 |6/3/2020 6:30:00 AM |
+-------------------+---------------+--------------------+


User_Table
+-------------------+---------------+
| User_Name         | User_ID       |
+-------------------+---------------+
| Keny              |             1 |
| Jhon              |             2 |
| Cira              |             3 |
| kyle              |             4 |
| Mandy             |             5 |
+-------------------+---------------+
```

This what I want to show in the result only for date_start yesterday (Interval -1 day)

```
+-------------------+---------------+
| User_Name         | Meeting_Count |
+-------------------+---------------+
| Keny              |             1 |
| Jhon              |             1 |
| Cira              |             0 |
| kyle              |             0 |
| Mandy             |             0 |
+-------------------+---------------+
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: As mentioned, see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a `left join` and aggregation:

```
select u.user_id, u.user_name, count(m.user_id)
from user_table u left join
     meeting_table m
     on m.user_id = u.user_id and
        m.date >= curdate() - interval 1 day and
        m.date < curdate()
group by u.user_id, u.user_name;
```

Notes:

- This includes `user_id` in the aggregation, just in case two users have the same name.
- The date filtering goes in the `on` clause, not the `where` clause.

Comment: This works very well. :) Thanks a lot for the answer. have a great day to u.